# site code giving error

Tags: r, sqldf, rsqlite

I wanted to create a database so that i could graph some things out of the database using various packages. But while creating the graphs i had some problems with the code. For eg i pulled the following code chunk from https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-sqlite-part-1/

```
library(sqldf)
baba <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname= "Test.sqlite")

dbSendQuery(conn = baba,
       “CREATE TABLE School
       (SchID INTEGER,
        Location TEXT,
        Authority TEXT,
        SchSize TEXT)”)
 dbSendQuery(conn = baba,
         “INSERT INTO School
         VALUES (1, ‘urban’, ‘state’, ‘medium’)”)
 dbSendQuery(conn = baba,
         “INSERT INTO School
         VALUES (2, ‘urban’, ‘independent’, ‘large’)”)
 dbSendQuery(conn = baba,
         “INSERT INTO School
         VALUES (3, ‘rural’, ‘state’, ‘small’)”)
```

But while executing the code i get the following error

```
Error: unexpected input in:
"dbSendQuery(conn = baba,
       �"
```

Now this chunk is directly from the site. Is it wrong or are there are some parts that need to be changed for it to work. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please check the quotes.  It is not the same as `"`    Could be a problem with copy/paste

Comment: Yes, it looks like the blog post has "smart quotes" in the code which don't work in R and need to be replaced with regular quotes for this code to work properly.

Comment: How can i close this question without having an answer. Or i don't need to?